# Android TV/FireOS TV volume control

Tags: android, volume, android-tv, amazon-fire-tv, amazon-fire-os

I want to create a TV app to control output volume. For FireOS TV to be precise.

FireTV Stick does not have any system volume control for its users. So I tried creating a normal TV application to programmatically set volume using `AudioManager.setStreamVolume()` but it does **not** works.

To my surprise there is already an App called *Precise Volume Control* for phones (not optimized for TV) which actually works with FireTV Stick too by sideloading. Not just that, it allows to fine control volume upto 100 levels.

How is precise volume control able to do this in FireTV Stick. Can you point me in the right direction how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Transport controls are probably what you are looking for. They provide access to media playback controls. Can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaControllerCompat.TransportControls)

On TV apps, usually the UI is provided by some Leanback libraries. Which can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start)

There are Leanback Transport controls [here](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/playback/transport-controls)

Usually, you would also be responsible for the media that is being played if you use the transport controls.

Comment: Read the docs but still couldn't figure out how it will help control system volume